# CSS arrow with background

Tags: html, css

Does anyone know how to achieve this layout?. Arrow icon with a circle background that also overlap in the text link.

[image]

[Here is my codepen.](https://codepen.io/christine-tine27/pen/pobzxzK)

My HTML code:

```html
<a href="/dining.html" target="_blank" class="home-button">Find out more <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

My CSS code:

```css
.fa-long-arrow-right:before {
content: "\2192";
font-size: 43px;
font-weight: 100;
position: relative;
top: 7px;
border: 1px solid #f1eeea;
background: #f1eeea;
border-radius: 50%;
padding: 9px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an exemple.
Change `text-indent` and `left` to match your requirement.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
.fa-long-arrow-right:before {
  content: "\2192";
  font-size: 43px;
  font-weight: 100;
  position: relative;
  top: 7px;
  border: 1px solid #f1eeea;
  background: #f1eeea;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: -19px;
  z-index: -1;
  text-indent: 20px;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 70px;
  width: 70px;
  line-height: 70px;
}
```

```html
<a href="/dining.html" target="_blank" class="home-button">
  Find out more
  <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i>
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

**This might be helpful**

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.fa-long-arrow-right:before {
  content: "\2192";
  font-size: 2.4rem;
  font-weight: bold;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid #f1eeea;
  background: #f1eeea;
  border-radius: 50%;
  padding: 0.4rem;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  margin-left: -24px;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <a href="/dining.html" target="_blank" class="home-button">Find out more <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right"
      aria-hidden="true"></i>
  </a>
</body>

</html>
```